# How to Use Custom Template Tag in Combination With Django's Built-in "with" Tag?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have this simple tag:

**myapp/templatetags/my_filters.py**

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_bookmark_object(content_type, object_id):
    return Bookmark.objects.get(content_type=content_type, object_id=object_id)
```

In my template, I want to be able to do this:

```
{% load my_filters %}

{% with object as bookmark %}
  {% with bookmark_object=get_bookmark_object bookmark.content_type bookmark.object_id %}
    {% if bookmark.content_type.model == 'post' %}
      {% include 'content/post/object.html' with object=bookmark_object user_bookmark=bookmark %}
    {% elif bookmark.content_type.model == 'note' %}
      {% include 'content/note/object.html' with object=bookmark_object user_bookmark=bookmark %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
```

I get the error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /my-page/
'with' received an invalid token: 'bookmark.content_type'
```

**My question is:**

How do I use my custom `get_bookmark_object` template tag in a `with` statement? An example with code would help me clarify a lot.

Reference:
[Django's with built-in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#with)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you defined is a template tag, you can assign the value produced by the template tag with an `{% … as … %}` tag:

```
{% get_bookmark_object bookmark.content_type bookmark.object_id as bookmark_object %}
    …
```

Comment: Thanks! You are 100% right. I guess I don't need `with`.